# How to copy the first column from file A to file b?

Tags: perl, copy

I have just learned Perl programming and I need help. I want to copy 1 column from file A to a new file. In file A there are 3 columns and I only want to copy the first column file to the new file, can anyone help me?

**file_a.txt**

```
JJ | John Junior    | 300-400
SJ | Samuel Jackson | 500-600
CJ | Chris John     | 789-899
BB | Bernard Blaze  | 789-899
LV | Luis Villa     | 789-899
```

I want to copy the first column section into the new file:

**newfile.txt**

```
JJ
SJ
CJ
BB
LV
```

I found on internet that, I need to use delimiter tab(\t) to separate columns and use delimiter newline(\n) to split the lines.(but I don't get it)

I'm sorry I'm a beginner, maybe someone wants to help me. thank you

Comment: Shouldn't even need perl. `cut -d '|' -f1 file_a.txt > newfile.txt` from a shell.

Comment: ... or `cut -d' ' -f1` to not include the space.

Comment: Okay, I'm confused. The sample file you included seems to use `|` (Hence my first comment), or maybe `<space>|<space>`, as a column delimiter, but then you mention tabs? What are you using?

Comment: I learned to make the program, thank you for helping me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to filter out first column:

- `cut -d ' ' -f1 in_file > out_file` (UNIX/Linux/Mac OSX)
- `nawk '{ print $1 }' in_file > out_file` (UNIX/Linux/Mac OSX)

If you interested in perl script

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $in  = shift;
my $out = shift;

open my $fh_in, '<', $in
    or die "Couldn't open $in";
    
open my $fh_out, '>', $out
    or die "Couldn't open $out";

while( <$fh_in> ) {
    chomp;
    say $fh_out (split)[0];
}

close $fh_in;
close $fh_out;
```

Short version run as `script.pl in_file > out_file`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

say ((split)[0]) while <>;
```

Or even shorter with perl one liner

`perl -ane "print qq($F[0]\n)" in_file > out_file`

Comment: `perl -anE 'say $F[0]' in_file > out_file` if we're golfing.

Comment: Thank you so much this really helped me!

Comment: @Shawn or `perl -pe 's/ .*//' in_file > out_file` if we're _really_ golfing ;)